# Angular CSP_NONCE example

Tags: angular

Could anyone do me an example how to implement
CSP_NONCE in an angular app?
https://angular.io/api/core/CSP_NONCE

Comment: Did you check angular documentation:https://angular.io/guide/security#content-security-policy?

Comment: Docs are terrible